# PHP Regular Expression to capture server names that contain two letter state and three letter city?

Tags: php, regex

I have a long list of server host names and I need to pull the server host names that contain a two letter abbreviated state followed by a three letter abbreviated city.

For example:

server host names:
ohdubgh01sp,
nyobg38djek,
123ohdub123as,
oh2kjd

This regular expression should pull the first 3 but not the last.

What I have tried:

`$pattern = "/.*(al|ak|az|ar|ca|co|ct|de|fl|ga|hi|id|il|in|ia|ks|ky|la|me|md|ma|mi|mn|ms|mo|mt|ne|nv|nh|nj|nm|ny|nc|nd|oh|ok|or|pa|pr|ri|sc|sd|tn|tx|ut|vt|vi|va|wa|wv|wi|wy)([a-z]{3}).*/";`

This will cut my list in half but will still retrieve items such as 'barker'. What is a good regular expression that will give me the most accurate results? Thanks

Comment: Why *shouldn't* it retrieve `barker` (it has `ar` after all)? And the only reason I can see that it should retrieve the 'first three' host names listed in your question is because they contain `oh`, `ny`and `oh` again...Regular expressions are *fantastic* for parsing regular, predictable strings; they're not so good with (seemingly) arbitrary requirements.

Comment: According to your description, *barker* is a valid match. You need to explain what comes before (if anything) and after (if anything) the server host name. This will solve your *problem*.

Comment: Can you always guarantee the position of the 5 character string within the overall string?  i.e. will it always be at the beginning or after some string of numbers (like in your 3rd sample)?

Comment: Unfortuantley there is no guarantee where this pattern will exist. All that I know is that the three letters for the city will directly follow the state.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is far beyond the realm of regular expressions.

The fundamental problem with filtering anything for meaningful entries is the word "meaningful". Such a thing doesn't exist for computers - everything is meaningful (or meaningless, depending on how you look at it) to them. Given (what appears to be) a set of freely styled entries, the best we can hope to do is narrow it down to a more manageable size and then go through and prune the data by hand, because normal programs simply do not have the human-level intelligence and understanding necessary to do so.

Take your case, for example: you want to find a two-letter state followed by a three-letter city. Because your input list has no immediate discernible pattern to it (other than the city follows the state), there's very little you can do to have the program prune the list for you other than specifying every possible five-letter abbreviation for every valid state/city combination, and even then there'll still be junk that slips through. For example, if a valid state/city combination is "arche", then a server host named "archer" will get by. It's all Greek to the computer.

To answer your more immediate needs: since specifying every state/city combination will take you longer than just pruning by hand, I suggest just using your current regex, try your best to determine any other patterns shared by the server hosts (and apply them to the regex), and do the rest by hand.

Comment: Yeah, using my regex I was able to go from over 9k results doen to around 4500 so it helps some. Guess i'll be doing the rest by hand. This could take a while ;)

Comment: @amlane86 Best of luck and godspeed. \*salute\*